# Qual é a melhor forma de limpar a memória ao usar o LKJson no Delphi?

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-10, memory-leaks

Estou tendo problemas em limpar a os dados da memória quando uso LKJson no Delphi.

Testei usando FreeAndNil, Free, Destroy e FreeInstance. Em alguns casos recebo a seguinte mensagem ao fechar o aplicativo.

> An unexpected memory leak has occurred. The unexpected small block leaks are:
>
> 1 - 12 bytes: TJSONList x 1
>
> 13 - 20 bytes: TList x 1

O meu código é o seguinte;

```
var
  jlRetorno: TJSONList;
  joPessoa: TJSONObject;
  jlistaDetalhes: TJSONList;
  joDetalhe: TJSONObject;

function BuscarDetalhe(IdPessoa: Integer): Boolean;
begin
    with TFDQuery.Create(nil) do
    try 
        //...SQL
        Open;

        jlistaDetalhes := TJSONList.Create;

        Result := not IsEmpty;

        while not Eof do
        begin
            joDetalhe := TJSONObject.Create;

            joDetalhe.Add('tipo',   FieldByName('tipo').AsString);
            joDetalhe.Add('numero', FieldByName('numero').AsString);

            jlistaDetalhes.Add(joDetalhe);

            Next;
        end;
    finally
        Free;
    end;
end;
begin
with qryConsulta do 
try 
    //...SQL
    jlRetorno := TJSONList.Create;

    while not qryConsulta.Eof do
    begin
        joPessoa := TJSONObject.Create;

        with joPessoa do
        begin
            Add('id',   FieldByName('id').AsInteger);
            Add('nome', FieldByName('nome').AsString);
            Add('cpf',  FieldByName('cpf').AsString);

            if BuscarDetalhe(FieldByName('id').AsInteger) then
                Add('detalhes', jlistaDetalhes);
        end;

        jlRetorno.Add(joPessoa);

        Next;
    end;
    Result := ConverterJsonParaString(jlRetorno);
finally
    FreeAndNil(jlRetorno);
end;
end;
```

Neste caso, tenho problemas porque adiciono outros objetos dentro de listas e lista dentro de objetos. Quando crio um objeto simples e apenas chamo o Free, não tenho problemas. Acredito que tenho que finalizar um por um em sequência ou primeiro eliminar as listas de dentro dos objetos filhos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei encontrando um problema no meu código.

Tinha uma linha onde quando não existia um registro no banco de dados, o objeto era criado e não era vinculado ao objeto pai, consequentemente não podia ser destruido quando chamava o `FreeAndNil` no `finally`

Antes:

```
 jlistaDetalhes := TJSONList.Create;
```

Depois:

```
 if not IsEmpty then
      jlistaDetalhes := TJSONList.Create;
```

Então, agora basta destruir o objeto pai

```
FreeAndNil(jlRetorno);
```